# Generic method parameter with unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently having a problem with a generic method.
First of all, I have an abstract class which contains this abstract, generic, method:

```
abstract protected void myMethod<T> (List<T> myList);
```

Then, when implementing the method, I used `DateTime` as the list's type:

```
protected override void myMethod<DateTime>(List<DateTime> myList)
```

Up to this point, everything seemed ok. Then, the behaviour I found unexpected was that I couldn't access any DateTime method of the list items:

```
String date = ((DateTime)myList[0]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

*No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments*

So this is the problem, I can't manage to fix the error, no matter what casts I'm trying.
I should mention that I've just started working with C#, so maybe I haven't understood how the generic types should function.

L.E.
So what I'm exactly trying to do is create and complete some word documents from C#.
My parent, abstract class, will have 2 methods, createDocument and completeDocument. The createDocument one doesn't depend on the document, as the creation process will always be the same. So, I implemented it in the parent class. Then, the completeDocument method will depend on what document I want to complete, as I'll use different type of information, which will be added in different areas of the document. 
myMethod from above is the simplified version of what I was trying to achieve with completeDocument.

So, right now I have 2 different document types, meaning the base class is inherited twice. One document will need DateTime information, and, the other document, some different type.

Comment: Can you please show a [mcve]? You cannot _overrride_ a **generic** method with a constructed one, the correct _override_ would be `protected override void myMethod<T>`. You can only provide a generic argument when you call that method.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. The problem persists even when changing the type.

Comment: It's not about which type you use, you cannot use _any_ specific type while overriding. Maybe you meant to make the whole abstract class generic and then derive a `public ClassWithDateTime : BaseClass<DateTime>`. You may need to explain the context, what you are actually trying to achieve in order to get a useful answer.

Comment: This is just wrong. Regardless of generics, you're explcitly casting `myList[0]` to `DateTime`. This will either work or fail at compile time or runtime with a cast exception, but there is no way it can fail with the error you wrote.

Comment: While what the OP is attemping is probably not right, there is something odd going on.  [I just had a play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97SCP.png) - even the `d` variable only has 1 version of `ToString` (with no parameters) as far as the editor/intellisense is concerned.

Comment: Ah - it's not using `DateTime` as a type.  It's using it as a Type Parameter - ie it's treating it as though it's `T` just by another name.  Then within the method itself, it's not referring to the `DateTime` struct anymore.

Comment: Why do you have a generic method if it only works for `DateTime`? In your definition `DateTime` is the name of the generic type parameter (like `T` in the parent type's definition) which is shadowing the `System.DateTime` struct you're trying to reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method's generic parameter should be supplied when method is called not when it's overriden.

You have to add generic parameter to class and then specify concrete type in subclass

```
public abstract class A<T>
{
    abstract protected void myMethod(List<T> myList);
}

public class B : A<DateTime>
{
    protected override void myMethod(List<DateTime> myList)
    {
        var date = myList[0].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

    }
}
```

*Note*

If you could specify specific Type while overriding the method

```
public abstract class A
{
    abstract protected void myMethod<T>(List<T> myList);
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void myMethod<DateTime>(List<DateTime> myList)
    {
    }

}
```

Then following code

```
 A a = new B();
 a.myMethod(new List<string>());
```

Would be inconsistent, you are passing `List<strign>` to method and in fact it expects `List<DateTime>`.

In fact

```
protected override void myMethod<DateTime>(List<DateTime> myList)
```

just specifies new name of `T` to `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` in your statement

`protected override void myMethod<DateTime>(List<DateTime> myList)`

is **NOT** the `DateTime` class, instead , it's a generic class identifier. In most case we would like to call it `T`(it doesn't have to, any name is acceptable).  If you want your method to deal with `DateTime` only, you don't have to use generic class `T` at all.

Or if you do want to allow it to process multiple classes as input.You can  overload your methods. Or unless it is really necessary ,do something like following to determine the specific class:

```
         protected override void myMethod<T>(List<T> myList)
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
            { 
                //this is a List<DateTime>
                var list = (IList<DateTime>)myList;
                String str = list[0].ToString("yyyy");
            }
            else if(typeof(T) == typeof(String))
            {
                //this is a List<String>
            }
            else
            {
                //.....Other classes
            }
        }
        void test()
        {
            myMethod<String>(new List<String>());//this will access the "else if" part
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
namespace GenericMethodParameter
{
    abstract class TestClass
    {
        abstract protected void myMethod<T>(List<T> myList);
    }
    class Program:TestClass
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program=new Program();
            program.myMethod<DateTime>(new List<DateTime>(){DateTime.Now});
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        protected override void myMethod<T>(List<T> myList)
        {

            string dateTime = ((DateTime)(object)myList[0]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

            Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to cast T into object so then It can be cast to any data type   string dateTime = ((DateTime)(object)myList[0]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Comment: This does not resolve the OP's problem. Try it using the example provided by tchelidze under the 'Note:' section.

Comment: abstract class TestClass
    {        abstract protected void myMethod<T>(List<T> myList);    }
    class Program:TestClass
    {     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program=new Program();
            program.myMethod<DateTime>(new List<DateTime>(){DateTime.Now});    Console.ReadKey();  }

        protected override void myMethod<T>(List<T> myList)
        {
            string dateTime = ((DateTime)(object)myList[0]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

            Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

Comment: The OPs override uses DateTime as a generic type param. Nonetheless this does address the compile time error. A code snippet would be more useful than a screenshot.

Comment: Indeed, your solution worked without errors. But, as far as my knowledge goes, this misses the purpose of the generic types I'm trying to use. If I'd simply replace T with Object, in the parent method, it would still be working.

Comment: AH there was some issue attaching snippet that's why I attached screenshot

Comment: without casting it won't solve your issue in fact your problem is specific to an explicit but if you want to use it for other types then overrloading will save your time